# implementing small scale hardware High Availability Multi Zone Cloud Cluster for personal storage

Tags: cloud, load-balancing, high-availability, platform, cloud-storage

Recently I setup pydio self hosted storage which I access via app from phone, me and my brother in different city take advantage of this self hosted cloud storage.

However I realised if due to some reason server set up at my home goes offline due to hardware failure, power outage or network issue, either of us won't be able to access the storage remotely, so recently I started researching cloud computing and came across Multi Zone High Availability cloud storage implementations.
And I also came across with concept of floating IP, which is directed to load balancer server . So I think I would need three things:

1. **Implementation of Load Balancer**, a mechanism to handle two or more zone cloud storage server , so that if web server goes offline in city where I am the load balancer should redirect requester to the web server in other location.
2. **Cloud software that can be deployed** at these two location(or multi zone location) in a way that **concurrency** is maintained.
3. What **Platform** should I choose which is easily manageable and to maintain.

How should I go setting all the above? I have no experience in this field. Correct me if I am wrong in technical terms I mentioned above, but this would be a great learning experience  for me or anyone  trying to implement self hosted MZHA cloud storage.

Before posting here I read [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117646/where-can-i-ask-questions-on-cloud-computing), however as far as I understand my question is mostly software application layer level, so I think stackoverflow is the right place.